# Grid text alignment rules

Tags: website-design, design, text, grid, alignment

I was wondering if someone has come across rules used by web designers for text alignment in a grid.

I was observing that majority of text is aligned towards left, but financial figures with decimals are right aligned. So it made me wonder if someone has read any document which outlines the scenario's or context when the text could be center, left, right aligned?

Comment: That's not really anything particular to web design. That's standard typography, for the most part. Most text is left align for readability. Numbers are right aligned (or, more accurately, decimal point aligned) for the same reason...readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules that I follow are:

1. Right-align a block or column of whole numbers or of whole numbers and text.
2. Left-align a block or column of whole text.
3. Align numbers at the decimal point (or imaginary decimal point).

They aren't originally mine, but come from the [XLCubed blog](http://blog.xlcubed.com/2008/05/applied-gestalt-laws-table-alignment/)